# orient DB search on datetime field and get result data from linked dataset

Tags: orientdb

I am quite new to OrientDB and have some trouble that keeps me for days now:
I have two classes. "PAGES" is holding information about pages, "CHECKS" contains information about checks on these pages.
They are connected by a 1 > n linkset called page2chck
It looks like this

```
Class PAGES
+----+---------+---------------------------------+
| Id | Title   | Url                             |
+----+-------------------------------------------+
| 30 | Blahbla | http://www.test.com/test.html   |
+----+-------------------------------------------+
| 40 | sometxt | http://www.foo.org/dummy.html   |
+----+-------------------------------------------+

Class CHECKS
+---------------------+---------+
| Lastcheck           | Status  |
+-------------------------------+
| 2016-02-01 23:58:12 | OK      |
+-------------------------------+
| 2016-02-02 22:04:24 | OK      |
+-------------------------------+
| 2016-02-02 23:57:55 | ERR     |
+-------------------------------+
| 2016-02-01 23:59:01 | OK      |
+-------------------------------+
```

I created a linkset like this

```
CREATE LINK page2chck TYPE LINKSET FROM CHECKS.CH_PID to PAGES.Id INVERSE
```

Now I want to retrieve all Pages that do not have a check after 2016-02-03, and I want to show the last date they were checked and the status

What I tried was:

```
select Title, page2chck.Lastcheck, page2chck.Status from PAGES 
where date.asLong(page2chck.Lastcheck) < 1454540400
```

But it returns an empty result

However, to test the integrity of the relation I ran

```
select Title from PAGES where page2chck.CH_PID=30
```

which correctly returns "BlahBlah"

So I tried

```
page2chck.Lastcheck, page2chck.Status, Title from PAGES 
where page2chck.CH_PID=30
```

which returned

```
#   |@CLASS|page2chck|page2chck|Title                          
----+------+---------+---------+---------------------------------
0   |null  |[441]    |[441]    |BlahBlah
```

So basically I have two problems here:

1. How can I run comparison on the date of a linked class and
2. how can I show the fields of this class?

Comment: Hi, why don't use edges instead of linksets?

Comment: Because I thought it would not make sense, because we run Checks every day, so every day we'd have to create a lot of vertexes and edges. With linksets the DB takes care of the relation itself which - I thought - makes the insertion faster. But maybe I amwrong as I am new to OrientDB. How would a query using edges look like then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
CREATE LINK page2chck TYPE LINKSET FROM CHECKS.CH_PID to PAGES.Id INVERSE
```

Now From console

[image]

From Studio

[image]

You can use this query

```
SELECT Title, $checks[0].Lastcheck as Lastcheck , $checks[0].Status as Status FROM PAGES 
let $a = (select EXPAND(page2chck) from $parent.$current),
$checks= ( select Lastcheck, Status from $a where Lastcheck in 
( select max(Lastcheck) from $a where Lastcheck < DATE("2016-02-03 00:00:00")))
```

From console

[image]

From Studio

[image]

If you want to retrieve all Pages that do not have a check after 2016-02-03
you can use this query

```
select from (SELECT Title, $checks[0].Lastcheck as Lastcheck , $checks[0].Status as Status FROM PAGES 
let $a = ( select EXPAND(page2chck) from $parent.$current),
$checks= ( select Lastcheck, Status from $a where Lastcheck in ( select max(Lastcheck) from $a))
) where Lastcheck < DATE("2016-02-03 00:00:00")
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is it.
Still mysterious what went wrong with the timestamp but this does the trick perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found one of the problems in your query

```
select Title, page2chck.Lastcheck, page2chck.Status from PAGES where date.asLong(page2chck.Lastcheck) < 1454540400
```

**1454540400** means ***1970-01-17 21:02:20***, verifiable by

```
select DATE(1454540400)                        

----+------+-------------------
#   |@CLASS|DATE               
----+------+-------------------
0   |null  |1970-01-17 21:02:20
----+------+-------------------
```

---

BTW, you could create the linklist without the INVERSE

```
CREATE LINK chck2page TYPE LINKSET FROM CHECKS.CH_PID to PAGES.Id
```

and querying like this:

```
orientdb {db=pages_checks}> select chck2page.title, lastcheck, status from CHECKS where lastcheck < DATE("2016-02-01 23:59:10")


----+------+---------+-------------------+------
#   |@CLASS|chck2page|lastcheck          |status
----+------+---------+-------------------+------
0   |null  |blablabla|2016-02-01 23:58:12|OK    
1   |null  |foo      |2016-02-01 23:59:01|OK    
----+------+---------+-------------------+------
```